# MATLAB: Animating a 3D contour map over time

Tags: matlab

So I have a set of data that I am processing for a given time in MATLAB, I output my data into a 2D vector, these values store the amplitude of a wave, while their position in the matrix gives their location. I am plotting my data with just

```
mesh(plotMatrix)
```

What would be really nice if I could animate the wave moving with time, the way I do it for a given time is I am multplying my data by e^(omega*j*t) where t is fixed. I'd like to use

```
time = 0:periodRes:5*period;
```

For time, where I can generate different data set for different increments of time then animate this with a 3D plot to see a wave moving...

Answer (score 0):

What about the [`movie`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) function? E.g.

```
time = linspace(0, 1, 30);
grid = linspace(0, 1, 30);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(grid, grid);

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
F = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);
for i = 1:numel(time)
    t = time(i);
    Z = t*sin(2*pi*(X-0.2*Y+t)); %// Sample function
    surf(X, Y, Z);
    zlim([-1, 1])

    drawnow
    F(i) = getframe;
end

subplot(1,2,2)
movie(F, 5)
```

Maybe in conjunction with [MovieWriter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html).